# If a committing peer is disconnected from the network, will other endorsing and committing peers commit transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi Hyperledger Experts:

Let's say there are two orgs:org1,org2

org1 has two peers: peer0.org1,peer1.org1. Similarly, org2 has two peers: peer0.org2,peer1.org2.

Assume that a transaction has been endorsed successfully, and been put to a block. Next step is committing the block to the ledger. If suddenly, peer1.org1 is disconnected from the network, or peer1.org1 is shutdown, what will happen? Will the remaining three peers also commit the block to their respective ledger? And if the answer is yes, what will happen when peer1.org1 recovers and reconnects to the network? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as peers are receiving blocks from the orderer nodes (or via gossip from other peers), they will validate and commit blocks/transactions (assuming the transactions are valid).  If any peer "disconnects" from other peers / orderers, once it reconnects it will pick up where it left off and process blocks.